# Nodejs code emits wrong md5 for content sometimes

Tags: node.js

I have some nodejs code that gzips a file and also calculates the md5 of the gzipped and non-gzipped version of the code. The md5 for the gzipped version is wrong sometimes (approx. 5 times out of a 1000 runs). Any ideas why it would happen?
Tested on linux with node v10.15.3 and version v14.15.2
Code-

```
  1 const fs = require("fs");
  2 const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;
  3 const zlib = require('zlib');
  4
  5 const crypto =  require("crypto");
  6 var filename= "abc.txt"
  7 var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
  8 var r = fs.createReadStream(filename);
  9 var w = fs.createWriteStream(filename + ".gz");
 10 var md5Generator = crypto.createHash('md5');
 11 var md5GeneratorGzipped = crypto.createHash('md5');
 12 var md5 = "";
 13 var md5zipped = "";
 14 var readSource1 = new PassThrough();
 15 var readSource2 = new PassThrough();
 16 var readSource3 = new PassThrough();
 17 var readSource4 = new PassThrough();
 18
 19 r.on('error', function(error){
 20                 w.destroy(error);
 21                 console.log("ERROR: r.on" + error);
 22                         });
 23
 24 w.on('finish', () => {
 25    console.log("file:"+ filename + ",md5:" + md5 + ",md5zipped:" + md5zipped);
 26 });
 27
 28 w.on('error', (err) => {
 29         console.log("ERROR: w.on" + err);
 30     });
 31
 32 readSource2.on('finish', () =>{
 33         md5 = md5Generator.digest('base64');
 34         console.log("readSource2.on finish");
 35     });
 36
 37 readSource3.on('finish', () =>{
 38               md5zipped = md5GeneratorGzipped.digest('base64');
 39         console.log("readSource3.on finish");
 40     });
 41
 42 readSource4.on('finish', () =>{
 43         console.log("readSource4.on finish");
 44     });
 45
 46 readSource1.on('finish', () =>{
 47         console.log("readSource1.on finish");
 48     });
 49
 50 readSource2.pipe(md5Generator);
 51 readSource1.pipe(gzip).pipe(readSource3).pipe(readSource4);
 52 readSource3.pipe(md5GeneratorGzipped);
 53 readSource4.pipe(w);
 54 r.pipe(readSource1).pipe(readSource2);
 55
```

Comment: Same results on 10 and 14? Have you tested your RAM?

Comment: You should probably check for errors at every stage of the pipe, since they are not propagated. Try [`stream.pipeline()`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) or [`pumpify()`](https://github.com/mafintosh/pumpify).